# Possible to "tunnel" PHP extension from Docker to outside?

Tags: php, docker, php-extension

On a CentOS 7 Virtual Machine, I have a PHP script running in Apache. That PHP script requires a PHP extension which I cannot install on the Virtual Machine. However, I have found a Docker image which contains the extension I need.

Now, how do I proceed from here?

Is it somehow possible to "tunnel" the PHP extension from inside the Docker to its host?

Or is it wise to make a detour over the command line? I.e. in the outer PHP script, call a system command which runs the Docker image, which runs a PHP script with the extension I need.

Comment: What's the extension, and why can't it be installed on a VM?

Comment: If you have a docker container with the extension, why not create your own container?

Comment: By it's very nature, the extension should be available to you from the Docker container. There should be no need to "tunnel". What is this mysterious extension?

Comment: Just run your web application in the Docker container. The VM's IP address will be mapped to the container and you will not need to run Apache on the VM host.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I don't get what you mean. How exactly is a PHP extension installed within a Docker container available on the Virtual Machine which runs the Docker container? I'm a Docker newbie. The extension I'm talking about is Saxon/C (see http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml) and the reason it can't be installed on the VM is mainly connected to right policies.

Comment: You treat the container as your web application server and don't worry about the host machine/VM

Answer (score 0):

possible? yeah, make some api doing the required actions inside the VM, serialize the result, and deserialize it where your main app is running. the serialization process may be done with serialize() or json_encode() or var_export(), the transfer protocol can trivially be implemented using HTTP or HTTPS (just use apache or nginx?). PS, you may want to add some authentication or ip whitelist.

am curious why you can't install the extension on your main system tho, i guess it's' a windows<->linux compatibility issue?